# Масштабирование в Chrome

Tags: css3, css

Здравствуйте.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с масштабированием в Chrome. Есть сайт http://www.training.od.ua 
Верстался с помощью rem. При уменьшении масштаба в Chrome начинает ломаться верстка. В Firefox все нормально.

Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: если вы масштабируете с помощью Ctrl +, Ctrl -, то это я считаю развлечением, не более. Ооочень редко когда оно бывает полезным

Comment: Если изначально текст читабельным, то это не особо нужная функция и не стоит заморачиваться. Лучше, больше времени уделите разным форматам мониторов и экранов, тогда и верстка в порядке будет.